# Can I restore lost sessions in Chrome's Session Manager extension?

Tags: mac, google-chrome-extensions

Not sure how this happened, but all my saved sessions in the Chrome extension Session Manager are now gone.

Does anyone know what to look for in a backup, to restore these?

Comment: Just in case it helps: typing `chrome://extensions` in your location bar and then enabling "developer mode", will show you the id of the extension. Given that id, see [Where does Chrome store extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions) and [Where to find extensions installed folder for Google Chrome on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377337/where-to-find-extensions-installed-folder-for-google-chrome-on-mac) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I restore a deleted Chrome browser session?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/201814/can-i-restore-a-deleted-chrome-browser-session) by same author on Ask Different.

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: very sorry about the duplications but thank you for the responses